# Firebase query function only returns false. (all the code works except for the boolean var doesExist)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
fun checkQuery(pathString: String, childPath: String, userInput: String): Boolean{
            var doesExist = false
            //query initializer
            val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(pathString).orderByChild(childPath).equalTo(userInput)
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
                //checks to see if data exists in the query
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.childrenCount > 0) {
                        doesExist = true
                    }
                } })
            return doesExist
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you're showing, I would fully expect every call to the function to return false.  The reason is because Firebase queries are asynchronous and return immediately, before the query is complete.  The callback you provide is invoke some time later, after the query is complete.  As such, the initial value of `doesExist` will not change before the function returns.

If you're trying to make a Firebase query return some value immediately, that's not a good idea to try, as it would cause your app to freeze (and possibly ANR) the main thread while the user waits for a query that might never complete.

Comment: ok thank you, so is there no possible way i could make a function to check a firebase query for data and return true if it exists?

Comment: As I said, that's not a good idea for the reason I mentioned.  You can make a function that itself takes a callback that receives the eventual boolean value.  Or you can use a LiveData to receive updates.  Or you can use coroutines to hide the details of the asynchronous call.  But making a synchronous function to return a boolean is not a good idea on Android.